# Texture doesn't have the texture but only the texture color

Tags: texturing

I made a landscape in blender but if i use my texture it isn't using the texture but the texture color. Please Help me[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94MI2.png)

Comment: have you unwrapped your mesh?

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a dupe of that question; that said either you need to unwrap the  mesh (Cycles by default tries to use UVs for image texture) or use generated type of texture coordinates; create Texture Coordinates node, get its output Object to input of Image Texture node and in the latter switch texture projection to Box.